# Passing in a binary function into a Scheme function

Tags: scheme, racket

Apologies if this is a common question. Searching up "Racket passing in lambda as an argument" doesn't return much. I'm trying to write a Racket function `lsf` that takes in an optional lambda function, and applies it to corresponding elements in two same-sized lists. This lambda defaults to addition.

For example, `> (lsf '(2 4 5) '(6 7 8) (lambda (a b) (- b a)))` should return a list `'(4 3 3)`

`> (lsf '(2 5) '(3 6))` returns `'(5 11)` (defaults to addition).

Here's what I have so far:

```
( define ( lsf list1 list2 )
    ( if ( null? list1 )
        '()
        ( cons( + ( car list1 list2 )) 
            ( lsf ( cdr list1 ) ( cdr list2 )))
    )
)
```

How do I add this default addition function as a parameter (I think it goes after list2?), and how would I use it in place of the "+" that I have after cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to *rest-args* and *optionals* (see other answers), Racket still has [`case-lambda`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/lambda.html#(form._((quote._%7E23%7E25kernel)._case-lambda))) (as in r6rs Scheme), so:

```
#lang racket

(define lsf
  (case-lambda
    [(list1 list2) ;; (Listof Number) (Listof Number) -> (Listof Number)
     ;; produce list of sums of corresponding elements of list1, list2
     (lsf list1 list2 +) ]
    [(list1 list2 combine) ;; (Listof X) (Listof Y) (X Y -> Z) -> (Listof Z)
     ;; produce list applying combine to corresponding elements
     (if (null? list1)
         '()
         (cons (combine (car list1) (car list2)) 
               (lsf (cdr list1) (cdr list2) combine))) ]))
```

And then:

```
> (lsf '(2 5) '(3 6))
'(5 11)

> (lsf '(1 2 3) '(#\a #\b #\c) make-string)
'("a" "bb" "ccc")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.` in the parameter list to define a *rest-arg*, which gets a list of all the additional arguments. If the optional argument is supplied, this will be non-null and you can get the argument as its first element.

```
(define (lsf list1 list2 . rest)
  (if (null? list1)
      '()
      (let ((func (if (null? rest) + (first rest)))) ; default func to +
        (cons (func (car list1) (car list2))
              (lsf (cdr list1) (cdr list2) func)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is `#lang racket` that is used you can use [by position optional parameters](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/lambda.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._lambda%29%29):

```
(define (lsf list1 list2 [combine +])
  (if (null? list1)
      '()
      (cons (combine (car list1) (car list2))
            (lsf (cdr list1) (cdr list2) combine))))
```