# creating a scheme struct list and functions to use it

Tags: scheme

```
 (define-struct groceryItem( id description price))

(define grocery-master-list(list (make-groceryItem 1 "bread" 1.99)
                                 (make-groceryItem 2 "milk" 2.99)
                                 (make-groceryItem 3 "carrots" 3.45)
                                 (make-groceryItem 4 "cookies" 4.55)
                                 (make-groceryItem 5 "sauce" 3.80)
                                 (make-groceryItem 6 "steaks" 8.25)
                                 (make-groceryItem 7 "apples" 5.65)))

(define StructObj (make-groceryItem 1 "bread" 1.99))
(groceryItem-id StructObj)
(groceryItem-description StructObj)
(groceryItem-price StructObj)
```

I need to create a function called "lookup" that takes an id and a list (which initially should be the list defined above) as parameters and returns the object from the list that matches the id. need to use car and cdr functions. This is what created as the lookup function but its totally wrong...need help

```
  (define lookup 
     (lambda( id grocery-master-list)
       (if(null? grocery-master-list) '()
          (if (= id ( groceryItem-id (car grocery-master-list))) (groceryItem-description(car grocery-master-list))
             (lookup id (cdr grocery-master-list))
           )
       )
     )
  )
```

Below, is an example of what the call to the lookup function should look like.

```
(lookup 3 grocery-master-list)
```

Comment: Your `lookup` function is based on the right idea (it's not totally wrong): you may be able to fix it by (a) getting parentheses right (where do parentheses go in `(define ... lambda ... args ... body` and `(if ... test ... then ... else` ?)  (b) thinking about what kind of thing each name is (what is `groceryItem-id` ?)  This function can be constructed systematically: have you learned that technique?

Comment: Your parentheses are all over the place. It looks like you're confusing the form `(define (name e0 e1 ...) body)` with the form `(define name (lambda (e0 e1 ...) body))`, and the conditional is also wrong.

Comment: You need to compare to the `id` of `(car grocery-master-list)`, and `groceryItem` is not an element of the list. You also need to consider what happens if the corresponding element doesn't exist.

Comment: systematically as in build function from the inside going out? I realized that I used the wrong form with too many parenthesis but not sure how to access each id within the struct list recursively. I updated my code but as of right now, its result is --> "bread"
       1.99
      "carrots"
>

Answer (score 1):

This is a sort of transcript of systematically constructing the `lookup` function (intermediate versions are commented out with `#;` - in practice one would just edit them to the next version)

The design method is [HtDF](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:UBCx+HtC1x+2T2017/77860a93562d40bda45e452ea064998b/#HtDF) (How to Design Functions): one writes down ***stub*** with ***signature*** and ***purpose***, ***examples***, ***template*** (copied from a library of standard templates). Takes a few minutes to construct a correct solution.

```
(define-struct groceryItem (id description price))

(define grocery-master-list (list (make-groceryItem 1 "bread" 1.99)
                                  (make-groceryItem 2 "milk" 2.99)
                                  (make-groceryItem 3 "carrots" 3.45)
                                  (make-groceryItem 4 "cookies" 4.55)
                                  (make-groceryItem 5 "sauce" 3.80)
                                  (make-groceryItem 6 "steaks" 8.25)
                                  (make-groceryItem 7 "apples" 5.65)))

#| I need to create a function called "lookup" that takes an id and a list
   (which initially should be the list defined above) as parameters
   and returns the object from the list that matches the id.
   need to use car and cdr functions. |#

(define notFoundGroceryItem (make-groceryItem 0 "" 0.0))

#;                                             ; *stub* ;; *signature*
(define (lookup id logi) ;; GroceryItemId ListOfGroceryItem -> GroceryItem
  ;; produce the item from logi with given id  ; *purpose statement*
  notFoundGroceryItem)                         ; *stub body* (valid result)
                                               ; *minimal example*
(check-expect (lookup 1 empty) notFoundGroceryItem )  ; (passes with above stub)

(define (fn lox) ;; ListOfX -> Y                  ; *template*
  ;; produce a Y from lox using natural recursion ;
  (cond                                           ;
    [(empty? lox) ... ]                           ; ...  = "base case value" ;; Y
    [else (....                                   ; .... = "inventory fn(s)" ;; X Y -> Y
           (first lox) (fn (rest lox))) ]))       ;

; groceryItem-id  ;; GroceryItem -> GroceryItemId           ; *inventory*
; =               ;; GroceryItemId GroceryItemId -> Boolean ;    
; car             ;; ListOfGroceryItem -> GroceryItem       ;
; cdr             ;; ListOfGroceryItem -> ListOfGroceryItem ;

                                  ; (substituting in template)
#;(define (lookup id logi) ;; GroceryItemId ListOfGroceryItem -> GroceryItem
  ;; produce the item from logi with given id
  (cond
    [(empty? logi) ... id ]       ;; GroceryItem
    [else (....
           id
           (car logi)             ;; GroceryItem
           (lookup id (cdr logi)) ;; GroceryItem
           ) ]))
                                  ; (use first check-expect to replace ...)
#;(define (lookup id logi) ;; GroceryItemId ListOfGroceryItem -> GroceryItem
  ;; produce the item from logi with given id
  (cond                           ; (first example still passes with this version)
    [(empty? logi) notFoundGroceryItem ] ;; GroceryItem
    [else (....
           id
           (car logi)
           (lookup id (cdr logi))
           ) ]))

(define grocery-test-list (list (make-groceryItem 1 "bread" 1.99)))

(check-expect (lookup  1 grocery-test-list) (make-groceryItem 1 "bread" 1.99) )
(check-expect (lookup 99 grocery-test-list) notFoundGroceryItem )

                                  ; (use above to deduce ....)
(define (lookup id logi) ;; GroceryItemId ListOfGroceryItem -> GroceryItem
  ;; produce the item from logi with given id
  (cond
    [(empty? logi) notFoundGroceryItem ]
    [else (if (= id (groceryItem-id (car logi)))
              (car logi)
              (lookup id (cdr logi))) ]))

(check-expect (lookup 3 grocery-master-list) (make-groceryItem 3 "carrots" 3.45))


Welcome to DrRacket, version 8.4 [cs].
Language: Beginning Student.
All 4 tests passed!
>
```

Comment: As originally posted, this answer does not deal with a requirement to make `grocery-master-list` a default (ie to allow `(gi-lookup id)` or `(gi-lookup id logi)`). Different ways of supplying default values for function arguments are covered in answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71260076/passing-in-a-binary-function-into-a-scheme-function)